# Can I use :lt selector with dynamic variable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-selectors

In my MVC project I want to refresh my page with new entries using AJAX.Everything is working great but I want to add some effect when displaying the new entries. First I use prepend like this:

```
$(".mCSB_container").prepend(data.htmlContent);
```

Then is I do this:

```
$(".entry:lt(4)").hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

It is working correctly.But, I would like to do it with a dynamic variable.I'm returning the new entry count from my Controller Action and set it like this:

```
 var count = data.count;
```

And when I want to use it like:

```
 $(".entry:lt(count)").hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

Visual studio show me the error message that says: `Expected <integer>`.I tried this when I defining the count:

```
 var count = new Number(data.count);
```

But that doesn't make any difference.Basically I want to select first `N` items with a given class, then hide and display them with fadeIn. How can I do it if the element count is dynamic ? Is it possible with `:lt` selector or is there another way I can use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation is what you are looking for

```
$(".entry:lt(" + count + ")").hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

but a faster alternate is to use [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$(".entry").slice(0, count).hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

Comment: is it really that simple? :p thanks for your answer and suggestion.I will accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @Selman22: Selectors are just strings. jQuery doesn't care how the string is created :)

Comment: @FelixKling yeah I noticed that.I'm really noob at jQuery :) that was a really simple one.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have concatenated the variable with the selector is wrong.

Try,

```
$(".entry:lt(" + count + ")").hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate your selector with variable using `+`:

```
$(".entry:lt(" + count + ")").hide().fadeIn(3000);
```